# Link click counter, and show how many times link is clicked

Tags: php, html

i want to count clicks when this link is clicked. AND show "how many times(number) link clicked"in example.com
not to use mysql.and better php if not,then javascript is ok

```
<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a pure JS implementation, you could use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) as follows:

```
<html>
<script>
    function init() {
        let count = localStorage.getItem('counter');
        if(count === null){
            count = 0;
            localStorage.setItem('counter', count);
        }
        count = parseInt(count);
        updateCount(count);
    }
    function incrementCounter() {
        let count = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('counter'));
        count = count + 1;
        localStorage.setItem('counter', count);
        updateCount(count);
        return true;
    }
    function updateCount(count) {
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "Clicked "+count+" times!";
    }
</script>
<body>
    <p id="count">-</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        init();
    </script>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" onclick="incrementCounter()">Google</a>
</body>
```

Comment: That will only give you the number of clicks of a specific client though. Not sure if OP wants that

Comment: Oh yes, in that case, client-side JS will not work